# Limit number of instances of Symfony Command

Tags: symfony, cron, symfony-console

I have a command in my Symfony app launched by Cron. I want to be able to limit the number of instances executed at the same time on my server, let's say 4 instances. I don't have any clue on how to do this. I found how to lock the command to launch the command only one time and wait for it to finish, but I don't know how to launch more than one and limit the number of instances anyway.
Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `semaphore`.

There is a `LockComponent` currently scheduled for 3.4 (was pulled from 3.3). It is a major improvement over the `LockHandler` in the `FilesystemComponent`.

In a pinch, you can probably pool a fixed number of locks from the `LockHandler`. I don't recommend it, because it uses `flock` on the filesystem. This limits the lock to a single server. Additionally, `flock` may be limited to the process scope on some systems.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\LockHandler;

define('LOCK_ID', 'some-identifier');
define('LOCK_MAX', 5);

$lockPool = [];

for ($i = 0; $i <= LOCK_MAX;) {
    $lockHandle = sprintf('%s-%s.lock', LOCK_ID, ++$i);
    $lockPool[$i] = new LockHandler($lockHandle);
}

$activeLock = null;
$lockTimeout = 60 * 1000;

$lockWaitStart = microtime(true);
while(!$activeLock) {
    foreach ($lockPool as $lockHandler) {
        if ($lockHandler->lock()) {
            $activeLock = $lockHandler;
            break 2;
        }
    }

    if ($lockTimeout && ($lockTimeout > microtime(true) - $lockWaitStart)) {
        break;
    }

    // Randomly wait between 0.1ms and 10ms
    usleep(mt_rand(100, 10000));
}
```

A much better and efficient solution would be to use the semaphore extension and work some magic with `ftok`, `shm_*` and `sem_*`.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use a process control system as supervisor. it's pretty simple to use and you can choose how many instance of your script you start.

http://supervisord.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shared counter file which holds a counter that gets increased when the Command starts running and decreases it before it's finished.

Another solution would be checking the process list with something like this:

```
$processCount = exec('ps aux | grep "some part of the console command you run" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l' );
if(!empty($processCount) && $processCount >= X) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "launcher command" executed by your cron or supervisor.

This Symfony commad can launch your instances with the [process component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) on your server. You can also check whatever you want to check and do everything you want to do like the `exec` php function.